# Nodes of intersection of hypersurface and a hyperplane

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It is known that an intersection of a general hyperpursuface of degree $\ge 5$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ and a hyperplane can have at most $3$ nodes.  My question is the following:
 Can these $3$ points lie on a line ?